# What is wrong with this proof of the variance of a binomial distribution?

Tags: variance, binomial-distribution

Obviously the variance isn’t zero, but I’m missing some foundational understanding and am having a hard time identifying why the setup is wrong:
[image: My attempt at the proof]

Already answered with comments but this is my question typed out:
For iid $X_1, …, X_n$ with $P[X_i=1]=p$ and $P[X_i=0]=1-p$ for i in $1, …, n$:
$$E[X_1+…+X_n]=E[X_1]+…+E[X_n]=np$$
$$Var[X_1+…+X_n]=E[(X_1+…+X_n-np)^2]=(E[X_1+…X_n-np])^2=0$$

Comment: Please consider typing your solution out in LaTeX so that those who rely on screen readers can also be involved. For your question itself, the arithmetic error lies in when you attempt to take the square out of the expectation. Things might be clearer if you expand the term $(X_1 + ... + X_n - np)^2$ in the expectation into terms involving $(X_1 + ... + X_n)$ and $(np)$.

Comment: The penultimate equality is *obviously* incorrect, because the only way the expectation of a squared quantity can be zero is when that quantity is *constantly* zero.  Focus, then, on how you intended to justify this equality.

Comment: In general, you can't assume $E(X^2) = [E(X)]^2.$ Let $Z$ be standard normal. Then $E(Z) = 0, [E(Z)]^2 = 0,$ but $E(Z^2) = 1 \ne 0.$

Comment: Operators are rarely transitive, it's a common error for students to act as if this is usually true. You have to carefully justify such interchanges of order of operations.

Comment: @Glen_b FWIW, interchanging the order of operations is, in its simplest form, referred to as *commutativity.*  For multiple operations, arbitrary permutations also require *associativity.*  Transitivity is a different concept.

Comment: Yes, I definitely mangled that. I don't even know why I wrote it that way.

Comment: @Glen No problem.  I was just picking a nit, as you know ;-).

Comment: Oh, it certainly called for a correction, I appreciate it.